What is the significance of the undocked state on the UI layout of the pane?
On the UI layout of the pane, there are operations of Dock and Undock.
We can see that in the undocked state, other interfaces will be covered. What is the function of the pane in the undocked state(I haven't found any convenient benefits of it)?
pane Dock state:

pane Undock state:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Similar question: Panels vs. Multiple Windows

These are generally useful when you are using multiple monitors – development/design on one and controls/inspection on another.

@Ren  do you meaning  floating pane, not docked pane?

Yes, floating ones. Separate them out, put them wherever is convenient. Split the screen and lay them out one after another.

Is this undocked pane draggable? can you move it around? If the application is not maximized, can you drag the pane outside of the main layout?


The undocked state allows the pane to be moved freely enabling users to reposition it anywhere on the screen. Helpful when needing to see more or less information at once or focus on specific content in the pane.
This becomes extra useful for users with multiple monitors – Users can drag the undocked pane to a different monitor, allowing for better use of screen real estate when working with multiple displays (as others have pointed out in the comments above)

